# Passing arguments wrapped with double quotes in a subprocess command

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.check_output()` method to execute commands from within the python script. There are some commands that need `"` (double quotes) to be present in syntax.

Here's one example:

```
> drozer console connect -c "run app.package.info -a com.package.name"
```

It throws error if we remove `"` (double quotes) from above command.

I did the following :

```
string = '\"run app.package.info -a com.package.name\"'
command = ['/usr/bin/drozer','console','connect','-c',string]
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

This yields me to error:

```
*** Unknown syntax: "run app.package.info  -a com.package.name"
```

How can I solve this issue of quotes?

Comment: You don't need to escape your double quotes btw.

Comment: Am new to python, was not aware about that. BTW, got to know new thing. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don’t need the double quotes.

The reason you need them with the shell command is that the shell is parsing the command line from a  string, and it uses them as an indication that the text `run app.package.info -a com.package.name` should be placed in a *single* argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

c_arg = 'run app.package.info -a com.package.name'
command = ['/usr/bin/drozer', 'console', 'connect', '-c', c_arg]
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
print("Got %r" % (output,))
```

When you’re using code to start a process, you explicitly specify individual arguments, and no shell parsing is going on, so there’s no need for the extra quotes.

Comment: I tried passing "run app.package.info -a com.package.name" without quotes but it gives error.

Comment: @v1h5 You need to change the line `string = '\"<whatever>\"'` by removing the `\"`s.  That should work.

Comment: @v1h5, "gives error" isn't clear enough for us to be very much help -- specify the exact thing you ran, and the exact error. This answer really is the best-practices approach, and identical to what the shell would do in the command line you gave.

Comment: @alastair : hi, I used "pexpect" module instead of "popen" and now everything is working fine.

Comment: I was thinking that problem was that double quotes were not sent correctly but didn't think of not sending them solves the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you need a split method that understands `subprocess` command argument requirements. Use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) like:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> import subprocess
>>> 
>>> command = 'drozer console connect -c "run app.package.info -a com.package.name"'
>>> command = shlex.split(command)
>>> command
['drozer', 'console', 'connect', '-c', 'run app.package.info -a com.package.name']
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use the option `shell=True` like:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: It’s best not to use the shell if you don’t have to.  Not only does it save creating an extra process, but it avoids any security risks associated with argument parsing.

Comment: Though the error is gone but now there is no output.

Comment: You need additional refactoring for this to work, and eventually adding a shell is something you want to avoid when it's not necessary. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)